# Windows ICMP Timestamp replies

Tags: windows, timestamp, icmp

I am trying measure the network latency (one way packet delay variation) using ICMP timestamp request/reply. The target computer is a Windows 7 computer. Unfortunately, I experience some issues with the ICMP timestamp rely sent by the Windows 7 computer:

- According to [Wireshark mailing list](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-bugs/201107/msg00278.html) there is a bug in the Windows 7 ICMP timestamp reply implementation: "[...] is a bug in the ICMP Timestamp implementation that provides the Timestamp reply in the wrong byte order [...]". Since I know this, I can handle this bug within my code that processes the received ICMP timestamp reply.
- It further seems that all timestamp replies sent by the Windows 7 computer only provide the seconds since midnight UTC instead of milliseconds. The timestamps are all of the form xxxxxxx000 (<- host byte order). But unfortunately milliseconds are needed to estimate the one way packet delay. Does anybody experience the same issues? Does anybody have an idea how to get millisecond time resolution?

Thanks in advance!
Jonas

Comment: maybe off-topic but do you know [iperf.exe](https://iperf.fr/) ?

Comment: As far as I know, iperf does not provide one way packet delay. Furthermore, iperf requires running a server on the receiver computer.